# Tracing registry operations in C#

Tags: c#, registry

I have a problem. I need to trace all read/write operations to the registry made  by various different programs.

I need to do this tracing from within a C# program.

Can I do this, or is it impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is you can.... :)

Sysinternals has developed a utility called [Regmon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896652.aspx) that does this thing. Then there is no reason to become this "Impossible"

But definitely some time will be needed to understand the procedure of doing this..

Update : I found a way of doing it.

[MSDN Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/0b8fd7c7-8abb-4423-a2b5-8f1c8f2ed16e/)

[CodeProject Article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/registrymonitor.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. But i have new question: can i trace changes from one specific program? 
I want that user choose one program and my application trace changes only for this program..

Comment: hmmm.. you have to get the PID/Process Name of the process that modifies the registry and then apply a filter.. :S